# black square appears around 1st Marker when a marker onClick triggers a state update

Tags: javascript, client, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

In my react App with package "@react-google-maps/api", I need to display a map with markers, and handle actions when markers are clicked. A marker's click launches a state update.

I see something strange since a while, a state update makes a black frame to appear around the 1st marker (first in the order they are given to ).

This is not nice and I want to hide it.

[image: black frame around marker when marker.onClick does state update]

- If the <Marker onClick={() => ... }> does only a "console.log", then no black frame appears.
- If the <Marker onClick={() => ... }> does a state update, then the black frame appears around the first marker (in the order of the list given)

I see this on Chrome and Edge (= Chromium), but not on Firefox.

Any idea how to hide this black frame ?

To reproduce:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/flelirzin/bug-marker-map.git
cd bug-marker-map
yarn install 
# please set google map api key in src/mapApiKey.js
yarn start
```

The button at the bottom can enable / disable the state update. When disabled, no issue.

The state update is simple and is to display lng/lat of the marker clicked.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Found the following bug on react-google-maps-api repo.

https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/2181

It tells the workaround of `version="3.43.8"` prop on `LoadScript`, which does the job well for me.